# Show selected/all columns when joining in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am joining these two data tables on id=ID and purchase_date between start_date and endate.

here is the code:

```
df1 <- data.table(ID=c(1,2,3),
                 start_date=c("2022-01-01","2022-10-15","2022-02-03"),
                 end_date=c("2022-01-03","2022-01-02","2022-01-01","2022-01-01"))

df1$start_date <- as.Date(df1$start_date)
df1$end_date <- as.Date(df1$end_date )

df2 <- data.table(id=c(1,1,7,8),
                 date_purchase=c("2022-01-05","2022-01-02","2022-01-01","2022-01-01"))

df2$date_purchase<-as.Date(df2$date_purchase)
```

The code to do this is the following:

```
df2[df1,.(x.date_purchase,id,ID,start_date,end_date), on=.(id=ID, date_purchase>=start_date, date_purchase<=end_date), nomatch=0]
```

I want to modify this code in a way that I only have to specify x.date_purchase, and add something that tells data.table I also want all remaining columns, and maybe specifiy all remaining from df1 or from df2. Is there a way to do this?

Expected output is this:

| ID | start_date | end_date | date_purchase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-02 |

Comment: you can use .SD instead of enumerating each col.

Comment: Apparently, .SD is showing only the columns of df2. I also need the columns of df1.

Comment: leave it empty `df1[df2, , on= ...]` and it will retrieve all columns from both tables.

Comment: This will make me lose the original purchase_date, which will be replaced by the boundaries "start_date" and "end_date". I need to specify that I need the x.purchase_date, plus all columns from the df1. So it'd be something like (x.date_purchase, df1$*). I am still not sure how to do it

Comment: Assuming `readr::read_delim`, your `df1` for me has six columns; are you really using `delim="\\s+"`?

Comment: When I change that to just `read.table(text="...", header=TRUE)`, we then need to change your date columns to be `Date`-class objects, otherwise `data.table` complains with `Only '==' operator is supported for columns of type character`. Can you please provide "real" data, perhaps using `dput(head(df1))` and similar? It is unambiguous and doesn't require us to chase bugs that aren't bugs in your real code.

Comment: Lastly, what is your expected output? While I _think_ I know based on your code, I recommend you remove doubt. Is your output effectively `df1[1,]` (1 row) with an added columns `date_purchase="2022-01-02"`?

Comment: Hi my bad, format was lost when copying. now the code should work without any modification in format or to the date. You'll automatically get the dates as date. I'll add the expected output

Comment: I see no changes at all. Please run `readr::read_delim("ID   start_date  end_date\n1   2022-01-01  2022-01-03")`; for me it returns six columns, not the three that are clearly intended. I recommend switching to `read.table(..., header=TRUE)` (and fix `Date`s) or use `dput(.)`, it seems clear that `readr::read_delim` is not working here.

Comment: will update the data.

Comment: data is corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed data:

```r
df1 <- read.table(text="ID   start_date  end_date
1   2022-01-01  2022-01-03
2   2022-10-15  2022-10-18
3   2022-02-03  2022-02-05",header=T) |> as.data.table()
df1[, c("start_date", "end_date") := lapply(.SD, as.Date), .SDcols = c("start_date", "end_date")]

df2 <- read.table(text="id   date_purchase
1   2022-01-05
1   2022-01-02
7   2022-01-01
8   2022-01-01",header=T) |> as.data.table()
df2[, date_purchase := as.Date(date_purchase)]
```

The issue is that on non-equi joins such as this, `data.table` is reassigning the value of the singular value (RHS) to the names of the non-equi (LHS) variables. Also, the RHS singular column can be omitted (as here). Frustrating, I don't know why.

```r
df1[df2, on = .(ID == id, start_date <= date_purchase, end_date >= date_purchase), nomatch = 0]
#       ID start_date   end_date
#    <int>     <Date>     <Date>
# 1:     1 2022-01-02 2022-01-02
```

Note (1) both start/end values are that of the desired `date_purchases`, and (2) we have no real `date_purchase`.

One workaround is to copy the start/end columns (LHS) to new names.

```r
df1[, c("start", "end") := .(start_date, end_date)]
out <- df1[df2, on = .(ID == id, start <= date_purchase, end >= date_purchase), nomatch = 0]
out
#       ID start_date   end_date      start        end
#    <int>     <Date>     <Date>     <Date>     <Date>
# 1:     1 2022-01-01 2022-01-03 2022-01-02 2022-01-02
```

While we don't have `date_purchase` by-name, the `start` and `end` columns both contain its value, so we can rename one and drop the other.

```r
setnames(out, 3, "date_purchase")[, end := NULL]
out
#       ID start_date date_purchase      start
#    <int>     <Date>        <Date>     <Date>
# 1:     1 2022-01-01    2022-01-03 2022-01-02
```

---

Raw data:

```r
df1 <- data.table::as.data.table(structure(list(ID = 1:3, start_date = structure(c(18993, 19280, 19026), class = "Date"), end_date = structure(c(18995, 19283, 19028), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
df2 <- data.table::as.data.table(structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 7L, 8L), date_purchase = structure(c(18997, 18994, 18993, 18993), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort regarding the data. Is there anyway to do something like: 
df2[df1,.(x.date_purchase,df1$*), on =...] where the "*" for example means all columns from the other table?

Comment: I don't understand. If I add arbitrary columns (not involved in the merge) to either or both `df1` and `df2`, they are all retained in `out`. For example, `df1[, c("a","b","c"):=.(1,2,3)]` and `df2[, c("aa","bb","cc"):=.(11,22,33)]`, then `out <- out <- df1[df2, ...]` (without cleanup) has all six of those extra columns.

Comment: your solution works perfectly. Just wanted to see if there a simple way like df$* that can be used in data.table, where we don't have to copy and then change the names etc. So a native solution.

Comment: `data.table` overwrites/changes names in non-equi joins. I don't know why, but it is what it is, unfortunately. This is a workaround I use in production (daily use). I don't love it, but it is stable and effective.

Answer (score 1):

A bit ugly, but you could use `foverlaps` which sadly needs two ranges (a "start" and "end") in both tables.

You could simply create a duplicate column by reference.

```
df2[, dummy := date_purchase]

setkey(df1, ID, start_date, end_date)
setkey(df2, id, date_purchase, dummy)

foverlaps(df2, df1, nomatch = 0)[, dummy := NULL][]

# id start_date   end_date date_purchase
# 1:  1 2022-01-01 2022-01-03    2022-01-02
```